# Como gravar informação de bit no banco SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro em VB e preciso de ajuda para gravar a informação de um `CheckBox` no banco de dados SQL Server.

A coluna esta em `bit` no banco, não sei como passar o parâmetro para que a escolha do usuário seja gravado no banco.

No caso do `Nchar` uso o seguinte parâmetro:

```
.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Nome", SqlDbType.Nchar)).Value = txtNome.Text
```

Mas no caso do `bit` estou fazendo algo errado:

```
.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ativo", SqlDbType.bit)).Value = chbAtivo.Checked
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Faça isto:

```
Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ativo", SqlDbType.bit)).Value =
                                             Convert.ToInt32(chbAtivo.Checked)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Bit.cs).

A propriedade é um booliano, tem um `true` ou `false`. Ao contrário do que pode parecer o tipo `BIT` do SQL Server é um inteiro que só permite os valores 0 e 1 e que pode ter alguma otimização de armazenamento. Então tem que converter o booliano para inteiro para gravar. E quando for ler vai ter que transformar este inteiro em booliano. Em alguns contextos existem outras soluções possíveis, mas tentei não inventar e só fazer o que está pedindo e mostrando.

Comment: Obrigado bigown, deu certo, so uma duvida tinha que converter a propriedade do CheckBox de Int para bit?

Comment: O contrário. A propriedade é um booleano, tem um `true` ou `false`. AO contrário do que pode parecer o tipo `BIT` do SQL Server é um inteiro que só permite os valores 0 e 1 e que pode ter alguma otimização de armazenamento. Então tem que converter o booleano para inteiro para gravar. E quando for ler vai ter que transformar este inteiro em booleano. Em alguns contextos existem outras soluções possíveis, mas tentei não inventar e só fazer o que está pedindo e mostrando.